# GDB garbles source and command window

Tags: c, ubuntu, gdb

I'm running gdb in an Ubuntu VM and am not able to get it to run without what seems like it breaking.  Everything gets garbled after about the third `n` next command.  Is there any way to realistically use gdb?  Am I supposed to just debug with `printf`'s?  How do the pros debug?

From the command line:

```
make
gdb
```

In `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static void Greet(uint16_t num_times) {
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_times; i++) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
  }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Greet(atoi(argv[1]));
  return 0;
}
```

In `makefile`:

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb
main: main.o

clean:
    rm -f main main.o
```

In `.gdbinit`:

```
file ./main
set args 3

# Breakpoints
break main

# Put source on top
layout src

run
```

Comment: "How do the pros debug?"  I use lots of assertions; I only use a debugger when assertions don't yield joy.

Comment: does it help to replace "-ggdb" with just "-g" in your  Makefile?  When you try it, do a "make clean" before you do "make".

Comment: same results when compiling with -g and -ggdb

Comment: You'll be better off not using GDB TUI (Text User Interface). It uses curses and my experience is that it tends to muck up the terminal. That is, leave out `layout src`.

Comment: When using gdb's TUI for programs that write to stdout or stderr, you can use the `set inferior-tty` command to use a terminal that's in a different window (to create one, open a gnome-terminal or xterm window, and in it type `tty; sleep 99999`). You can also use `M-X gdb` in emacs for another kind of text-based interface to gdb.

Comment: @tarabyteTry putting "layout src"  below the "run" command